# Is this integral solvable with some substitution?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there a general way to solve analytically the following type of integral?

$$\int e^{-x} \frac{f'(e^{-x})}{f(e^{-x})}dx$$

I am thinking about some substitution but I don't see a direct result.

Comment: Which substitutions have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int e^{-x} \frac{f'(e^{-x})}{f(e^{-x})} \ \mathrm dx
&=& \displaystyle -\int \frac{f'(e^{-x})}{f(e^{-x})} \ \mathrm de^{-x} \\
&=& \displaystyle -\int \frac{f'(u)}{f(u)} \ \mathrm du \\
&=& \displaystyle -\int \frac{1}{f(u)} \ \mathrm df(u) \\
&=& \displaystyle -\ln f(u) + C \\
&=& \displaystyle -\ln f(e^{-x}) + C \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that by the chain rule$$\frac d{dx} \log f(e^{-x}) = \frac{f'(e^{-x})}{f(e^{-x})}(-e^{-x})$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\int e^{-x} \frac{f'(e^{-x})}{f(e^{-x})}dx=-\int  \frac{(-e^{-x})f'(e^{-x})}{f(e^{-x})}dx$$